# Mocking method with javax.ws.rs.core.Response and assertion

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking, response, testcase

I have a main method that implements/calls another method. I'm writing a test case for the main method where I have to mock the response of the calling method.

```
public String getAccount(String add, String sub) {
...
Response r = getService(add, sub);
...
}

public Response getName(String add, String sub) {
...
Response r = WebTarget.path(pathString).queryParam("aaa", "xxxx").queryParam("byId", add)
            .request().header("accept", "json")
            .header("Authorization",token).get();
return r;
}
```

I'm trying to write a test case here so that I can mock the response of getName to return non-200 response.

```
@Test
public void testGetAccount(){
when(getName).thenReturn(...);//How do I mock this?
String result = getAccount(anyString, anyString);
assertNotEqual(Https.Ok);
}
```

How do I mock the response of getName method here?

Comment: Your test code in its current form will not compile, even assuming the blank `...` were filled in.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
 MyResponseObject myResponseObject= MyResponseObject(); 
    Response 
     response=Response.status(Response.Status.OK).entity(myResponseObject).build(); 
     when(getName(anyString, anyString)).thenReturn(response);
```